# CSS support for inkscape's PDF to SVG conversion

Tags: css, pdf, svg, inkscape

converting a PDF page to a SVG document works OK with inkscape.
However I noticed that many style elements are heavily duplicated in the output SVG.

I noticed that embedding CSS into SVG [seems to be possible](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Web-Style.html) using inkscape's UI.
Does anyone know if (and how) this CSS conversion can be called from inkscape's command-line (or through some inkscape API) as well?

Kind regards,
Marius

Comment: I don't know about Inkscape API but you can always use some CSS parser to optimize your css. Eg: csstidy and merge_selectors?